# How can i refresh two jqGrid's from the same asp.net-mvc controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have 2 jqGrid tables and i want to refresh then from the same asp.net-mvc controller action. Right now I am doing this seperately but its a waste as the original source of the data for both tables is the same so i am running the same query on the backend twice.  Ideally i would like to call the mvc controller action once and then return 2 different datasets back to the client.

Is this possible with jqGrid and asp.net-mvc?

Comment: I think you'll have to use invoke your action once, get the two datasets and then use the dataset with local as the datatype on the jqgrid. If your action isnt taking very long, it might be best to have two different actions.

Comment: please post your controller actions and refresh calls on your post.

Comment: Do you use `loadonce: true` option in the grids? How many total number of rows are in the dataset which will be displayed in the  grids? If processing of query on the backend is relatively slow (expensive) and **the total number of at least one from the grids** not so large (<1000 or 10000 rows) then usage of `loadonce: true` would be recommened. In the case one can easy implement the scenario which you asked in your question.

Comment: @Oleg - i don't have loadonce: true.  The total rows in the grids in this case are quite small and they always get refreshed at the the same time (as they represent different aggregations of the same underlying dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use one grid with `datatype: "json"` and `loadonce: true` options (I name it "the first grid" later) and another grid with `datatype: "local"`. The response from the server should contains *two* parts: one with the *full* data (all pages) for the first grid and the second one with the *full* data for the second grid. The `root` property of `jsonReader` of the first grid can be configured to process the first part. The callback `beforeProcessing` of the first grid can be used to clear the second grid, to set `data` parameter and to reload the second grid. The advantage of `beforeProcessing` in the scenario is executing only in case of Ajax calls to the server. `loadComplete` for example will be executed on local sorting or paging too. The "Refresh" button of the second grid can be defined so that it set `datatype` of *the first* grid to `"json"` and then trigger "reloadGrid" of *the first* grid. The call of `navGrid` of the first grid (which adds "Refresh" button) should contains `beforeRefresh` callback which reset `datatype` to `"json"`. In the way all refreshing of grids will refresh the data from the server instead of local reloading.

Implementing of the above scenario will do all what you need. You will additionally reduce the number of calls of the URL and improve the responsibility of both grids because of usage `loadonce: true`. In the case sorting, paging and filtering/searching of data in both grids will be implemented *locally* by jqGrid. No calls of server, very quick paging, sorting and filtering.

Comment: thanks . . are there any examples of this working? I am trying to follow what you are saying but i seem to be running into an issue.  Instead of asking another question figured i would first ask if there are any examples

Comment: @leora: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TwoGridsInOneJson.htm). It's an example of the implementation which I described.

Comment: this does look like it works, would it be worth while setting both the grids to use local data and then use a javascript function to load the data for both grids at the same time from an mvc url?

Comment: @TerryKernan: It's possible, but I don't see that it's really required. The usage of `datatype: "json", loadonce: true` seems me more corresponds to what one do. Why one should make *separate* Ajax request if jqGrid can do the same for you?

Comment: @Oleg I looked at the TwoGridsInOneJson.json file and it loads two separate data sources, but they could be easily joined though, the op asked to use the exact same data source, but it's a small step to do that from what you have done.

Comment: @TerryKernan: The data for two tables from TwoGridsInOneJson.json have no common parts. It's just an example of two independent tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could return JSON data from the action and populate both grids using the local datatype as shown below.
The example is from http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html under the array data tab.

Edit: ah, just saw this is what sumit was thinking in the comments as well.

```
jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        height: 250,
        colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
            {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
            {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
            {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
            {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},     
            {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},      
            {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
        ],
        multiselect: true,
        caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
    });
    var mydata = [
            {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
            {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
            {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
            {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
            {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
            {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
            {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
            {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
            {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
            ];
    for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
        jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);
```